# Unable to connect to Azure using JDBC (based upon the connection string and samples provide) due to SSL issue

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, ssl, jdbc

Am getting the following error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Connection reset by peer: socket write error."

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;

public class SQLDatabaseConnection {

    // Connect to your database.
    // Replace server name, username, and password with your credentials
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionString =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://XXXXX.database.windows.net:1433;"
                        + "database=VDB;"
                        + "user=XXX@VVV;"
                        + "password=XXXX;"
                        + "encrypt=true;"
                        + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
                        + "hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;"
                        + "loginTimeout=30;";

        // Declare the JDBC objects.
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try {
         //   Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

            // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
            String selectSql = "SELECT TOP 2 * from Application";
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql);

            // Print results from select statement
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2) + " "
                        + resultSet.getString(3));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Close the connections after the data has been handled.
            if (resultSet != null) try {
                resultSet.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (statement != null) try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (connection != null) try {
            connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only trying to do the "sample" connection snippet of code as referenced on the Azure site (which points to a MS entry), modified only to match my db and test table but without success.

Having reviewed all there is to know, I have:-

1. ensured that I'm using the right sqljdbc (I've tried all 4)
2. have the sqlauth.dll on the CLASSPATH
3. have set the sample up EXACTLY as shown; and incorporated the string that Azure offers.

I have tried various combinations of encrypt and trust without success.  As I'm a newbie to Java and Azure, I'm reluctant and unsure how to fiddle with the JVM security settings.

I've proven that my machine can talk to the Azure database (through a VB ODBC connection); and I've tested with the firewall down.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue, but failed that I could access my SQL Azure Instance using the code which be similar with yours.

The difference between our codes is only as below, besides using the connection string of my sql azure instance.

1. Using the driver `sqljdbc4.jar` from the `sqljdbc_4.0` [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774).
2. Using the code `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` to load MS SQL JDBC driver.
3. Not adding the `sqlauth.dll` file into the `CLASSPATH`.
4. Check my client IP which has been allowed by SQL Azure IP firewall.
5. Using the sql `select 1+1` to test my code, and get the value `4` from code `result.getInt(1)`.

That's fine for me. If you can supply more detals for us, I think it's very helpful for analysising the issue.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You might want to file a bug report if `select 1+1` results in 4 on SQL Azure ;)